# Golang mysql-driver: invalid connection

Tags: mysql, golang

Почему у меня не хочет подключаться к серверу `mysql` (стоит на локальном хосте: `Denwer`).
В Apache прописаны конфигурации: `$&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}`. 
Ошибка:

```
[mysql] 2017/11/29 20:56:50 packets.go:36: unexpected EOF
panic: invalid connection
```

Код:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func main() {
        ModuleCreateDatabase()
}
func ModuleCreateDatabase() *sql.DB {

   name := "testx"
   db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:echo123@tcp(127.0.0.1:80)/test")
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   defer db.Close()

   eerr = db.Ping()

   if eerr != nil {
       panic(eerr.Error())
   }
   _,err = db.Exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS "+name)
   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }
   db.Close()


   return db
}
```

Бд есть, таблица есть, все есть, локалхост работает по адресу который прописан в `Apache`. Пароль правильный: `echo123`.

Comment: После `Open` всегда надо делать [`Ping`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Ping). Что он выведет?

Comment: @Ainar-G кроме panic: exit status 2 нечего не выдает db.Ping()

Comment: @Ainar-G код на PHP $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=formm', 'root', ''); Как это на Golang написать? При помощи php отлично подключается к БД, а golang не хочет.

Comment: У меня нет опыта работы с MySQL; добавил вам тег. Могу только сказать, что просто "panic: exit status 2" быть не может, вы что-то упустили. Либо ошибка от `Open`, либо ошибка от `Ping` укажет вам, что не так.

Comment: Ну и да, почему вы в PHP и Go используете разные строки соединения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все теперь стало понятно. Не нужно усложнять себе задачу, просто нужно было заменить `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:echo123@tcp(127.0.0.1:80)/test")` на `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root@/test")`.